# Error while importing a custom module in colab

Tags: module, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import a custom module to my script but colab won't find the module from my drive. 
I'll add a screenshot so you can see the directory:

[Screenshot of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5LaR.png)

this is the code with which I am trying to import the module:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!cp "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heston/black_scholes.py"
import black_sholes
```

When I try to run this I get the following Error message:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'black_sholes'*

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your gdrive to `PYTHONPATH`:

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heston")

import black_scholes
```

If you don't want to modify the `sys.path` you can just run your module, but then you will loose `black_scholes` namespace:

```py
%run "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heston/black_scholes.py"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried modifying the `sys.path` before and also gave your code a try but unfortunately I still get the same error...

Comment: You have typo in `import black_sholes`. Should be `import black_scholes` :-)

Comment: your a hero! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dot at the end of

```
!cp "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heston/black_scholes.py"
```

It should be

```
!cp "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heston/black_scholes.py" .
```